# put a dynamic_cast in loop

Tags: c++, loops, casting, dynamic-cast

Is it correct to put `dynamic_cast` in loop??

```
//Searches for the reservation with the given reservation number, and   //deletes it. Uses the confirmReservation function if the reservation to be     //deleted was an OK one 
void cancelReservation(string resNum)
{
    for (int i=0;i<seats+waitingListMax;i++)
    {
        for (int seat=i;seat<seats;seat++)
        {
    Ok* okptr=dynamic_cast <Ok*>(reservations[seat]);
        }
        for ( int wait=seats;wait<seats+waitingListMax;wait++)
        {
    Waiting* waitingptr=dynamic_cast <Waiting*>(reservations[wait]);
        }
        if ((reservations[i]!=0) && (reservations[i]->getReservationNumber()==resNum))
            if (okptr)
            {
                //doing somting
            }
            if (waitptr)
            {
                //doing somthing else
            }
    }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be ok? I mean, your code just overwrites the same pointer time and time again, but the cast itself is fine.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? you are overwriting each cast with the next one.. onto a variable which is destroyed immediately after the loop finishes

Comment: It's ok, but not the way you have done. Your casts are overwriting, so effectively only the last one remains.

Comment: What is exactly your concern? vtbl lookup performance?

Comment: @KarthikT I'm going to cancel reservations and check its type. If it is an OK Reservation and there are Waiting reservations on the list, then the OK reservation will be deleted and call confirm function which will put the first Waiting reservation on the waiting list in place of a removed OK reservation

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong in putting it under a for loop.
Your class should be polymorphic though but that is a basic condition for using `dynamic_cast`.

In your example, You are not really acheiving much because you overwrite the pointer on every iteration. But that is probably your simplification of original code.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with using `dynamic_cast` within a loop.

But your code does have a different problem: the pointers `okptr` and `waitingptr` are only scoped to the innermost `{}`, so can't be used later.